# Error disappears when I click on hyperlink inside validationmessage mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, html-helper

Validation Error message is disappearing when I click on hyperlink inside validationmessage mvc

My validation message is

```
Please enter a &lt;a href='http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage.htm' title='Information Requests.'&gt;valid entity number&lt;/a&gt;.
```

On the webpage I have,

```
    @Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" }).ToString()))
```

The target url specified in href is not opening. The error message simply disappears. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `ModelState.AddModelError` in controller action method like there:

```
String message = "Please enter a <a href='http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage.htm' title='Information Requests.'>valid entity number</a>.";
ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", message);
```

Then you need this code to show the hyperlink part in view:

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" }).ToHtmlString()))
```

Instead of `ToString()` which just converting to string without changing HTML tags, use `ToHtmlString()` ([MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.tohtmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx)) which returns HTML-encoded string from `ValidationMessageFor`.

Simple example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wyJ5OY)

Similar issue:

[How can I render html in validation message in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999130/how-can-i-render-html-in-validation-message-in-asp-net-mvc)

[Link in validation summary message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907908/link-in-validation-summary-message)