# Adding ActionLink in @HtmlValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have custom validation for Unique field. Its working fine but is there a way to wrap my error message in ActionLink?

I tried something like this but it just doesnt works.

[Link in validation summary message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907908/link-in-validation-summary-message)

Or even better if my error message can be link.

EDIT:
TY guys for answers. I will explain it better. So, I have unique field. Its something like social security number. Point is there can only be one of those. So I made my custom validation for that. It works fine. It shows message that there is already SSN like that. But I want that as link so it can go in other view and show details for person with that SSN.I know how I can do that if I would know how to add Action link here:

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

So, I found that link up but I dont understand how it works becuase. If I only leave it like this:

@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary().ToHtmlString()))

It works. It shows property and model errors.But even if I add true just to not show property errors:

@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary(true).ToHtmlString()))

program breaks for null. I dont even know where to add ActionLink.

Model is

`public class PI
{ public Predavaci X { get; set; }
  public Adrese_predavaca Y { get; set; }
}`

SSN is part od X

Comment: I don't understand, why did the method found within the link you provided not work? Can you provide some more details please?

Comment: What is your use case? Why wouldn't you just let MVC do it's thing and show the error message with links on the view?

Comment: @SteveGreene I want that but where should I add links? I have this over my class [Validacije(ErrorMessage = "There is SNN with that number")]. It shows this error message. But how can I get something like this ActionLink("There is SNN with that number", "Index", "Nebitno")

Comment: @ZachPedigo I edited my post. I hope its clear now. I just never done it. Dont know where to add link.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from Endy's answer in your link, you could add a link/button that only appears when there is a duplicate SSN:

```
// Your field name. Get message from your validation attribute
@if (ViewData.ModelState["SSN"].Errors.Any(ms => ms.ErrorMessage == "Duplicate SSN."))  
{
    // controller action that displays person needs a parameter
    @Html.ActionLink("Go to SSN", "Index", "Nebitno", new { ssn = Model.SSN } )
}
```

Comment: So, I tried and it didnt work. When I changed your ModelState in ViewData.ModelState I have new problem. And it is the same that I get from all other solution that I try: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.this[string].get returned null.

Comment: @dsadsdasdas Sorry, in the view you need to use `ViewData.ModelState`. See edit.

Comment: TY but problem is here ViewData.ModelState["SSN"]. Its alwayes this System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.this[string].get returned null.

Comment: Is "SSN" the name of your model field? I just made that up since you did not include the model.

Comment: So your validation attributes are in Predavaci? Then "SSN" would become "x.SSN". You should be able to stop the debugger and see how ViewData.ModelState is returning the errors.